Labeling/positioning of grouped, stacked, circular barchart in R
I am trying to create a circular, stacked, and grouped bar chart using ggplot2. The problems I am having are

adjustment of prop labels within the chart itself. The labels positioning within the bars (the proportions) are not correlating to the areas they are supposed to represent
I would like the labels that are currently on the outside to be positioned within the inner circle, similar to this: https://r-graph-gallery.com/299-circular-stacked-barplot.html

My data looks like this:
    structure(list(`No of Carbon` = c(9, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 8, 9, 8, 
8, 13, 4, 6, 10, 6, 7, 6, 5, 5, 8, 11, 6, 2, 9, 8, 4, 14, 12, 
4, 4, 10, 6, 6, 9, 10, 9, 10, 4, 8, 6), `Functional Group` = c("Carboxylate", 
"Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", 
"Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", 
"Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Sulfonate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", 
"Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", 
"Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", 
"Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", 
"Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", 
"Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate"), `PFAS Type` = structure(c(28L, 
28L, 20L, 4L, 26L, 19L, 30L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 41L, 18L, 27L, 7L, 
27L, 24L, 26L, 37L, 37L, 33L, 17L, 27L, 36L, 28L, 30L, 19L, 40L, 
22L, 18L, 18L, 6L, 27L, 14L, 28L, 23L, 28L, 20L, 19L, 30L, 27L
), levels = c("4:2 Cl-PFESA", "4:2 FTS", "6:2 Cl-PFESA", "6:2 FTS", 
"6:2 H-PFESA", "8:2 Cl-PFESA", "8:2 FTS", "ADONA", "FBSA", "FHxSA", 
"FOSA", "FOSAA", "GenX", "HFPO-DA", "HFPO-TA", "N-Et-FOSAA", 
"N-Me-FOSAA", "PFBA", "PFBS", "PFDA", "PFDDA", "PFDoA", "PFDS", 
"PFHpA", "PFHpS", "PFHxA", "PFHxS", "PFNA", "PFNS", "PFOA", "PFONDS", 
"PFONS", "PFOS", "PFOSA", "PFOUDS", "PFPA", "PFPeA", "PFPeS", 
"PFTDA", "PFTeDA", "PFTrDA", "PFUA", "PFUdA", "PFUnA"), class = "factor"), 
    concentrations = c(0.45, 5.9, 0.83, 1.2, 0.82, 2.04, 12.7, 
    1.15, 2.71, 156, 0.71, 5.37, 0.00007, 0.04, 0.35, 0.19, 2.95, 
    0.26, 2.63, 0.96, 0.33, 117.18, 16, 0.4, 24, 0.45, 1.33, 
    3.57, 3.6, 3.15, 0.02, 0.97, 1.38, 0.34, 0.22, 1.34, 3.3, 
    5.27, 3.69, 3.54), carbon_chain = c("Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", 
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", 
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS"), group = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("rain", "stormwater", 
    "surface"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -40L), na.action = structure(c(`7` = 7L, 
`8` = 8L, `9` = 9L, `10` = 10L, `11` = 11L, `12` = 12L, `13` = 13L, 
`14` = 14L, `15` = 15L, `16` = 16L, `17` = 17L, `18` = 18L, `19` = 19L, 
`20` = 20L, `21` = 21L, `22` = 22L, `42` = 42L, `43` = 43L, `44` = 44L, 
`59` = 59L, `60` = 60L, `61` = 61L, `62` = 62L, `63` = 63L, `64` = 64L, 
`65` = 65L, `66` = 66L, `76` = 76L, `77` = 77L, `78` = 78L, `79` = 79L, 
`80` = 80L, `81` = 81L, `82` = 82L, `83` = 83L, `84` = 84L, `85` = 85L, 
`86` = 86L, `87` = 87L, `88` = 88L, `94` = 94L, `95` = 95L, `96` = 96L, 
`97` = 97L, `98` = 98L, `99` = 99L, `100` = 100L, `101` = 101L, 
`102` = 102L, `103` = 103L, `104` = 104L, `105` = 105L, `106` = 106L, 
`107` = 107L, `108` = 108L, `109` = 109L, `110` = 110L, `136` = 136L, 
`137` = 137L, `138` = 138L, `139` = 139L, `140` = 140L, `141` = 141L, 
`142` = 142L, `143` = 143L, `144` = 144L, `145` = 145L, `146` = 146L, 
`147` = 147L, `148` = 148L, `149` = 149L, `150` = 150L, `151` = 151L, 
`152` = 152L, `153` = 153L, `154` = 154L, `157` = 157L, `158` = 158L, 
`159` = 159L, `160` = 160L, `161` = 161L, `162` = 162L, `163` = 163L, 
`164` = 164L, `165` = 165L, `166` = 166L, `167` = 167L, `168` = 168L, 
`169` = 169L, `170` = 170L, `171` = 171L, `172` = 172L, `173` = 173L, 
`174` = 174L, `175` = 175L, `176` = 176L, `180` = 180L, `181` = 181L, 
`182` = 182L, `183` = 183L, `184` = 184L, `185` = 185L, `186` = 186L, 
`187` = 187L, `188` = 188L, `189` = 189L, `190` = 190L, `191` = 191L, 
`192` = 192L, `193` = 193L, `194` = 194L, `195` = 195L, `196` = 196L, 
`197` = 197L, `198` = 198L, `200` = 200L, `201` = 201L, `202` = 202L, 
`203` = 203L, `204` = 204L, `205` = 205L, `206` = 206L, `207` = 207L, 
`208` = 208L, `209` = 209L, `210` = 210L, `211` = 211L, `212` = 212L, 
`213` = 213L, `214` = 214L, `215` = 215L, `216` = 216L, `217` = 217L, 
`218` = 218L, `219` = 219L, `220` = 220L, `224` = 224L, `225` = 225L, 
`226` = 226L, `227` = 227L, `228` = 228L, `229` = 229L, `230` = 230L, 
`231` = 231L, `232` = 232L, `233` = 233L, `234` = 234L, `235` = 235L, 
`236` = 236L, `237` = 237L, `238` = 238L, `239` = 239L, `240` = 240L, 
`241` = 241L, `242` = 242L, `248` = 248L, `249` = 249L, `250` = 250L, 
`251` = 251L, `252` = 252L, `253` = 253L, `254` = 254L, `255` = 255L, 
`256` = 256L, `257` = 257L, `258` = 258L, `259` = 259L, `260` = 260L, 
`261` = 261L, `262` = 262L, `263` = 263L, `264` = 264L, `270` = 270L, 
`271` = 271L, `272` = 272L, `273` = 273L, `274` = 274L, `275` = 275L, 
`276` = 276L, `277` = 277L, `278` = 278L, `279` = 279L, `280` = 280L, 
`281` = 281L, `282` = 282L, `283` = 283L, `284` = 284L, `285` = 285L, 
`286` = 286L, `290` = 290L, `291` = 291L, `292` = 292L, `293` = 293L, 
`294` = 294L, `295` = 295L, `296` = 296L, `297` = 297L, `298` = 298L, 
`299` = 299L, `300` = 300L, `301` = 301L, `302` = 302L, `303` = 303L, 
`304` = 304L, `305` = 305L, `306` = 306L, `307` = 307L, `308` = 308L, 
`311` = 311L, `312` = 312L, `313` = 313L, `314` = 314L, `315` = 315L, 
`316` = 316L, `317` = 317L, `318` = 318L, `319` = 319L, `320` = 320L, 
`321` = 321L, `322` = 322L, `323` = 323L, `324` = 324L, `325` = 325L, 
`326` = 326L, `327` = 327L, `328` = 328L, `329` = 329L, `330` = 330L, 
`333` = 333L, `334` = 334L, `335` = 335L, `336` = 336L, `337` = 337L, 
`338` = 338L, `339` = 339L, `340` = 340L, `341` = 341L, `342` = 342L, 
`343` = 343L, `344` = 344L, `345` = 345L, `346` = 346L, `347` = 347L, 
`348` = 348L, `349` = 349L, `350` = 350L, `351` = 351L, `352` = 352L, 
`355` = 355L, `356` = 356L, `357` = 357L, `358` = 358L, `359` = 359L, 
`360` = 360L, `361` = 361L, `362` = 362L, `363` = 363L, `364` = 364L, 
`365` = 365L, `366` = 366L, `367` = 367L, `368` = 368L, `369` = 369L, 
`370` = 370L, `371` = 371L, `372` = 372L, `373` = 373L, `374` = 374L
), class = "omit"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

This is currently what I have done:
    df %>% 
  summarise(N = n(), .by = c(group, carbon_chain, `Functional Group`)) |> 
  arrange(desc(`Functional Group`), carbon_chain, group) |> 
  mutate(
    prop = N / sum(N), 
    label_y = cumsum(prop),
    x = paste0(group, "\n", carbon_chain),
    .by = c(group, carbon_chain)
  ) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = prop, fill = `Functional Group`)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", color = "black") +
  geom_label(aes(y = label_y, label = scales::percent(prop, 1)), fill = "white",
             show.legend = F, position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size = 2) +
  coord_polar() + 
  ylim(c(-1, NA)) + # hole size
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray", linetype = "dotted"),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )

What my current graph looks like
So you can see that the prop labels are not centered to their respective parts and the outer labels look messy. I'm thinking to have these, currently outer labels, on the inside and non repetitive. So one inner layer of labels would be 'Rain' 'Surface' and 'Stormwater' and these would each cover two 'bars'. A second inner label would cover long vs short chain

For your label layer, use y = prop in the aesthetics and position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5) to align it with the col layer.

As already mentioned by @teunbrand in the comments you can solve your first issue by mapping prop on y and using position_stack. For the second issue you can follow the example from the R graph gallery and first create a data frame to draw the segments for the inner circle, where instead of geom_segment and geom_text I use geomtextpath::geom_textsegment which allows to draw the segments and text in one go and allows for curved text. Additionally I switched to geomtextpath::coord_curvedpolar() which allows for curved x axis text labels, where for the latter I dropped the information on the group as this is now reflected in the inner circle. If instead you want the axis text as a second inner circle you can follow the approach I used for the first inner circle.
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data <- df %>%
  distinct(group, carbon_chain) %>%
  arrange(group, carbon_chain) |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  summarise(
    start = min(id) - .4,
    end = max(id) + .4,
    .by = group
  ) |>
  mutate(title = rowMeans(across(c(start, end))))

df %>%
  summarise(N = n(), .by = c(group, carbon_chain, `Functional Group`)) |>
  arrange(desc(`Functional Group`), carbon_chain, group) |>
  mutate(
    prop = N / sum(N),
    x = paste0(group, "_", carbon_chain),
    .by = c(group, carbon_chain)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = prop, fill = `Functional Group`)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", color = "black") +
  geom_label(
    aes(y = prop, label = scales::percent(prop, 1)),
    fill = "white",
    show.legend = FALSE,
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
    size = 8 / .pt
  ) +
  # Add base line information
  geomtextpath::geom_textsegment(
    data = base_data,
    aes(
      x = start, y = -.1,
      xend = end, yend = -.1,
      label = group
    ),
    colour = "black",
    linewidth = 0.6,
    size = 8 / .pt,
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    gap = FALSE,
    offset = unit(-8, "pt")
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = ~ gsub("^.*?_", "", .x)
  ) +
  geomtextpath::coord_curvedpolar() +
  ylim(c(-1, NA)) + # hole size
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray", linetype = "dotted"),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = .5),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )


